# Xcode swift 3 cocoapods error

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am getting this error after installing a CocoaPod and I don't understand why:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can somebody give me an answer?

Comment: Are you using the Workspace CocoaPods created or the Project that you where using before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are using the Xcode Project (`.xcodeproj`) that you where using before.

When you install a pod, you need to use the Xcode Workspace (`.xcworkspace`) that CocoaPods automatically creates for you:

[image]

Comment: @ViorelWWI That's great! Because this answer solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted by select the check mark next to it. This will let other people know your problem was solved (and you'll get rep).